# How to make a highchart pathfill blink/flicker continuisly

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts in one of my application. Basically based on the content I want to highlight that particular stroke. Currently I could achieve that but my requirement is to keep it blinking/flickeing showing as if there is an something wrong in that particular point. can someone help me, how to achieve this?

```
<path
fill="rgba(214,45,32,0.5)"
d="M 472 125.83319815668202 A 30 30 0 1 1 471.99998500000123 125.803198161682 Z" 
stroke="#d62d20"
stroke-width="2"
class="highcharts-point highcharts-negative highcharts-color-1 highcharts-point-hover"
>

</path>
```

Comment: code snippet:
<path fill="rgba(214,45,32,0.5)" d="M 472 125.83319815668202 A 30 30 0 1 1 471.99998500000123 125.803198161682 Z" stroke="#d62d20" stroke-width="2" class="highcharts-point highcharts-negative highcharts-color-1 highcharts-point-hover"></path>

Comment: Put your code in the post not as a comment please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Highcharts `animate` method to achieve the wanted result:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var point = this.series[0].points[2];

                function toRed() {
                    point.graphic.animate({
                        fill: '#ff0000'
                    }, {
                        duration: 300
                    }, toBlue);
                }

                function toBlue() {
                    point.graphic.animate({
                        fill: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)'
                    }, {
                        duration: 300
                    }, toRed);
                }

                toRed();
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bxa64930/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#animate